# After I delete a row in SQLite database with the listview id, the listview shows wrong content of new item on the same position

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

This is really hard to explain but I'll try.

I have a Listview that shows all items, that are currently saved in the SQLite Database. But the Listview only shows part of the content of the dataset row.
When you click on a listview item a new Activity(ResultEntryActivity) is started, where all of the rows content is displayed. In that activity I wanted the user to be able to delete this entry when he/she klicks on a button. Then an intent brings the user back to the SearchEntryActivity where the listview is.
The listview item then is deleted, but when I klick on the item that is now on the position where the just deleted item has been, no content is shown in the ResultEntryActivity. But somehow the listview item itself(which shows part of the content) shows the right content...
Does anyone know how to fix this? I really need it to work.

These are the important methodes from the SearchEntryActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    initDb();
    initListView();
    initAdapter();
    setItemListener();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    myDb.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initDb() {
    myDb = HomeActivity.myDb;
    myDb.open();
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getAdapter.swapItems(myDb.getAllEntryItems(0, "list"));
}

private void initListView() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
}

private void initAdapter() {
    myList = myDb.getAllEntryItems(0, "list");
    Collections.sort(myList);
    getAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, myList);
    listView.setAdapter(getAdapter);
}

private void setItemListener() {

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ResultEntryActivity.class);
            id += 1;
            i.putExtra("entryId", id);
            i.putExtra("listItemId", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

These are the important methods from ResultEntryActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_entry);

    initComponents();
    initDb();
    viewAll();
    deleteEntry();
}
private void deleteEntry() {
    deleteEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(buttonAnimation);
            showAlert();

        }
    });
}

private void showAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder passwordDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ResultEntryActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_alert_layout, null);

    Button yes = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.button_yes);
    Button no = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.button_no);

    dialog = passwordDialog.create();
    dialog.setView(layout);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.startAnimation(buttonAnimation);
                dialog.dismiss();
                myDb.deleteEntry(""+entryId+"");
                Toast.makeText(ResultEntryActivity.this, entryDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(ResultEntryActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("position", entryId);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.startAnimation(buttonAnimation);
                //Eintrag soll nicht gelöscht werden -> Alert Dialog wird einfach geschlossen und nichts passiert.
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    dialog.show();
}

private void initDb() {
    myDb = HomeActivity.myDb;
    myDb.open();
}

private void initComponents() {
    imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    mapImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_image_view);
    dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_date);
    dateView.setPaintFlags(dateView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    headlineView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_headline);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    editEntry = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.edit_this_entry);
    deleteEntry = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.delete_this_entry);
}

public void viewAll(){
    Bundle idBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    entryId = (long) idBundle.get("entryId");
    System.out.println(entryId);
    myDb.getAllEntryItems(entryId, "entry");
}
```

And this is from my Database:

```
public ArrayList<EntryItem> getAllEntryItems(long id, String entryOrList) {
    if(entryOrList.equals("entry")){
        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_DATE, COL_HEAD, COL_IMAGE, COL_MAP,COL_TEXT }, COL_ID + "=" + id +"", null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String date = cursor.getString(INDEX_DATE);
                ResultEntryActivity.dateView.setText(date);
                String headline = cursor.getString(INDEX_HEAD);
                ResultEntryActivity.headlineView.setText(headline);
                String text = cursor.getString(INDEX_TEXT);
                ResultEntryActivity.textView.setText(text);
                byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(INDEX_IMAGE);
                if(image !=null){
                    ResultEntryActivity.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ResultEntryActivity.imageView.setImageBitmap(DbBitmapUtility.getImage(image));
                }
                byte[] map = cursor.getBlob(INDEX_MAP);
                if(map != null){
                    ResultEntryActivity.mapImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ResultEntryActivity.mapImageView.setImageBitmap(DbBitmapUtility.getImage(map));
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }else if(entryOrList.equals("list")){
        ArrayList<EntryItem> listItems = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COL_ID, COL_DATE,
                COL_HEAD, COL_IMAGE }, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String date = cursor.getString(INDEX_DATE);
                String headline = cursor.getString(INDEX_HEAD);
                if(cursor.getBlob(INDEX_IMAGE) != null){
                    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(INDEX_IMAGE);
                    listItems.add(new EntryItem(date, headline, image, null, null));
                }else {
                    listItems.add(new EntryItem(date, headline, null, null, null));
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return listItems;
    }
    return null;
}

public void deleteEntry(String id){
    database.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
}
```

I hope I added everything thats relevant. Sorry that it's so much but I really need the help.
Thanks.

Comment: remove this: `id += 1;` you have to use an `id` which is passed by your adapter, not `id + 1`

Comment: thanks but even with the id that is passed by the adapter nothing has changed.

Comment: So use the right adapter: `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: It's working with SimpleCursorAdapter. Thank you very much!

Comment: and i believe your code is more simple now,  isnt it?